# Splitting line every x meters using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, splitting, general-transit-feed-specification

I have a line that I ultimately want to split up into points. The points should be every 100 meter along the line. So I don't want to extract the nodes.

Are there any Open Source (QGIS, Python) tools around for that?

The use case is that I have a bus line without bus stops. Though I know every 100 meter the bus stops. This way I want to generate bus stops to use as a GTFS feed.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63201/how-to-create-points-in-a-specified-distance-along-the-line-in-qgis and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85415/how-to-split-lines-into-equal-segments-with-qgis

Comment: What do you need in the end? Both points and split lines, only points, or only split lines?

Comment: @gcarrillo In the end I only need the points.

Comment: @AndreJ Yes this is a duplicated. I am sorry for not researching better beforehand. This should be closed.

Comment: You got some new answers as well...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **Convert lines to points** tool (you need SAGA GIS installed and the processing toolbox plugin enabled) and set your distance:

[image: Convert lines to points]

This is what I received for my line layer:

[image: Line and points]

I used the **Measure Line** tool from the toolbar to do a quick check between points:

[image: Measured line]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This tool seems to preserve all the vertices of the original linestring and add more points to long segments. Maybe it does not give an exact solution to the question `So I don't want to extract the nodes`

Comment: GRASS `v.split.length` or `v.to.points` from the same processing toolbox might be better tools.

Comment: @AndreJ, I agree although you would have to be careful with `v.split.length`. As it spits out a line layer, when converting this to points it will give duplicates on the inner vertices of the entire line (since each segment has a start-and-end). Atleast this is what happened to me when I tried it. But `v.to.points` should work.

Comment: You can buffer and centroid the duplicates. `v.to.points` does not split, if that is needed.

Comment: @AndreJ, yup true. Very simple extra steps.

Answer (score 7):

May be an alternative to the suggestion AndreaJ gave- Have look at

[Station Lines](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/stationlines/)

N.B. This tool expects projected coordinate systems for the feature to be splitted by planar length  unit.

[image: SL]

Comment: Awesome! I just tested this plugin and it's pretty useful. Good shout!

Comment: Looks very interesting. Though it doesn't have any metadata what it does or what the input parameters are. Would you mind . Would you mind adding a little example on how to use it?

Comment: To get points, you can create buffers around the station lines, then calculate the centroids of the buffers.

Answer (score 3):

Can be done with OpenJUMP and linear referencing tools. Select the line layer first.

[image]

Fill in the parameters

[image]

Results go to a new point layer. Points are at equal intervals along the line, original vertices are dropped. Start and end nodes can be preserved if desired.

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Very nice and simple! I should use OpenJUMP more often.

Comment: I wish we could have those ideas in QGIS plugins as well!